# Attached Excel document is received blank

Tags: vba, excel

I created a form in Excel to email to a specific distribution, however when its coming as an email all of the data is lost.

I found a thread where it tells me that I need to add coding to tell it to save the user's data. I cant locate how to add this.

```vb
Sub Sendit()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim Mess As Object, Recip As String
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Mess = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With Mess
        .To = "user@email.co.uk"
        .BCC = Range("I12").Value
        .Subject = "A new Bright Idea has been submitted"
        .Body = "A new Bright Idea is attached."
        .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName
        .Send
        MsgBox "Thank you for sharing your Bright Idea. You will be contacted once our Bright Ideas meeting has taken place with an update on the progress so far"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the .Attachmets.Add function the workbook must be saved to the file system first.

You can auto save without user interaction/confirmation using something like this (needs to go before your Outlook send code)-

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'DISABLE ALERT PROMPT

Dim BookName 
BookName = Range("A1").Value 'for example

'SAVES FILE USING THE VARIABLE BookName AS FILENAME
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Data\" & BookName, FileFormat:= _
xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
, CreateBackup:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'RESETS DISPLAY ALERTS
```